# How can I automatically inject Grails components declared in resources.groovy into my IntegrationSpecs?

Tags: grails, groovy, spock

Using the Spock (0.7) Grails (2.1.2) plugin you can write integration specifications that automatically inject Grails archetypes (like services). However, I would like to do the same thing for Spring beans declared only in my `resources.groovy`. For example:

```
beans = {
    simpleBean(SimpleBean) {
        // load some dependencies
    }
}
```

Where SimpleBean is declared in the `src/groovy` folder. If this were a Grails service, I could write something like the following in my `test/integration` folder::

```
import grails.plugin.spock.IntegrationSpec

class SimpleBeanSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    def simpleBean

    def "should"() {
        when:
            data = simpleBean.load()
        then:
            assert simpleBean
    }

}
```

But the above throws a `NullPointerException` on the call to `simpleBean.load()`. Is there some way to get Spock/Grails to create the the simpleBean dependency so that it has all the configured depdencies from `resources.groovy` as you would a Grails service?

Answer (score 0):

Grails automatically injects all beans into integration tests, including Spock tests.  Beans declared in `resources.conf` should work the same as artefacts. Are your IntegrationSpecs located under `test/integration`?

Comment: The tests are in test/integration, I'll update the question to reflect that but this is definitely not working on my install of Grails.